# Unable to locate element inside the iframe using protractor for non-angular webpage

Tags: protractor

Getting the following error while executing the below js. Please advise.

HTML:

```html
<div id="iframeContainer">
<iframe class="selectedModulesIframe" frameborder="0" src="XXXXXX/?locale=en&amp;security={&quot;language&quot;:&quot;en&quot;,&quot;token&quot;:&quot;LYu1sFnCa6UHRTEs1Xsa3bs7&quot;,&quot;agentId&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SSHAIK&quot;},&quot;organisation&quot;:&quot;RAIL-NSWT&quot;,&quot;distributedContextID&quot;:null,&quot;securityModeCode&quot;:null}&amp;module=SCHEDULECHANGELIST" id="SCHEDULE1552627852125" name="SCHEDULE1552627852125" style="height: 519px; width: 1903px;">
</iframe>
</div>

<span id="w10" atdelegate="d6" class="xWidget" style="width:85px;margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
<a class="xLink_std" href="javascript:(function(){})()" tabindex="1&quot;">192429</a>
</span>
```

Here is my code:

```
browser.switchTo().frame(browser.driver.findElement(protractor.By.tagName('iframe'))).then(function(){
        console.log('Iframe switch')
        browser.driver.findElement(protractor.By.linkText("192429")).click().then(function(){
            console.log('action performed') 
        })

    })
```

Also try the below code:

```
browser.switchTo().frame(browser.driver.findElement(protractor.By.tagName('iframe'))).then(function(){
        console.log('Iframe switch')
        element(by.linkText('192429')).click();
```

})

**Error response:**

**[16:49:46] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:49:46] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
Got the iframe
Iframe switch
[31mF[0m
Failures:
1) Affected Passenger Notification Verify APR in Schedule Change UI
  Message:
[31m    Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"192429"}
      (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)[0m
  Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"192429"}
      (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\sshaik\eclipse-workspace\Protractor_Orion\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)**

HTML:

Comment: From the code you posted that element you require is not within the Iframe. I assume that is an error in your question?

Answer (score 1):

```html
//It works with the below code.

const iframeLocator = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('iframe.selectedModulesIframe'));
         browser.switchTo().frame(iframeLocator).then(function(){
          
          var EC4 = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
          browser.wait(EC4.visibilityOf(element(by.linkText('192429'))),70000).then(function(){
           console.log('Got the iframe Id');
          })
          browser.driver.findElement(protractor.By.linkText('192429')).click().then(function(){
            
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
const iframeLocator = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('iframe.selectedModulesIframe'));

   goToIFrame: function () {
        browser.switchTo().frame(iframeLocator );
    },

    goToDefault: function () {
        browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: @SOHAILAHAMED mark the answer as correct since it help other who face the same issue.